Cannot install new JDK in Visual Studio Code. Any solutions to my problem?
I have recently just downloaded VS code for my class and am trying to set up vs code to code in java. I am trying to downlad a jdk, Adoptium's Temurin 11 (LTS), but it won't let me. The tab that it opens whenever I try installing a new jdk remains loading and will not stop. preventing me from choosing and installing the jdk.
My computer is microsoft surface laptop using 64 bit arm-based processor.
I have followed these steps:

download vscode (for windows 10/11 arm 64 bit)
install these extensions: extention pack for java, checkstyle for java.
uninstall extensions: maven for java, intellicode.
search show and run commands > java: install new jdk.

I am trying to choose Adoptium's Temurin 11 (LTS), but it won't let me. The tab that it opens remains loading and will not stop.
enter image description here
I have unistalled and reinstalled fully multiple times, and cleared everything in json settings to refresh my vs code, but no matter what I get this problem. The steps I have followed are exactly what my teacher has instructed and none of the TAs were able to help me fix this problem. I have never downloaded any previous jdks or any java programs on this computer and my teacher does not want us using redhat (the website vscode directs me to when i click the notification in the bottom as seen by the picture).
Any suggestions to fix this problem?

I'm not aware of Java 11 existing for Windows arm64. It seems the JDK had been ported to Windows on ARM starting with version 16. You should try installing version 17 (since 16 is no longer supported but 17 is a Long-Term-Support version). But why not use the latest version 22 or the latest LTS version 21?

By the way, did you read the error message? It says "Java 17 or more recent is required". Is there any specific reason you need Java 11? That's quite an old version.

@k314159
I am using lts 11 because that is the one we are using in class. I asked the TAs in my class, and they want us to use that version and nothing else. These steps worked for my other classmates, so I am not sure why only mine will not allow it.

Are your classmates also using a Microsoft Surface? If they are using x64 laptops, Java 11 would be available. By the way, it could be worth challenging the TAs over not allowing more recent versions. Java 17 is backward-compatible with 11, so there should be no problem using it.

Other vendors
Adoptium appears to have no releases for Windows on ARM.
You can try several other JDK vendors. These include Amazon, Microsoft, Oracle, Azul Systems, BellSoft, IBM, Red Hat, SAP, and more.
I checked Azul Systems. That vendor offers Java 17 and 21, both LTS versions, for Windows on ARM.
Be aware that you can install later version of Java, then compile your app for an earlier version.
Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code
To use Java in VS Code, use the Oracle extension.
See article, Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code. To quote:

This allows us to offer VS Code IDE support for new JDK features as soon as they are introduced, even during Early Access of the JDK. To this effect, our VS Code Extension will support the current JDK releases as well as the next upcoming JDK version.

The current version of Java is 22, with 21 being the most recent LTS. See Java version history at Wikipedia.
